# java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, non-static

I have error  java:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

when compiling the code in line

```
Man m1 = new Man("a1", "b1", 11);
```

How to fix that?

```
public class Solution
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //create two object of every class here
      Man m1 = new Man("a1", "b1", 11);
      Man m2 = new Man("a2", "b2", 12);
      Woman w1 = new Woman("a11", "b11", 13);
      Woman w2 = new Woman("a22", "b22", 14);

       //output them to screen here
       System.out.println(m1.name + " " + m1.age + " " + m1.address);
        System.out.println(m2.name + " " + m2.age + " " + m2.address);
        System.out.println(w1.name + " " + w1.age + " " + w1.address);
        System.out.println(w2.name + " " + w2.age + " " + w2.address);
}

    //add your classes here
    public class Man
    {
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private int age;

        public Man(String name, String address, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

or more simply ([mycompiler.io fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/CXnsefOpBM6))

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tester("hello");
    }
    
    class Tester {
        public Tester(String s) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want help to understand what the error means, or simply help to fix the problem? A static context means you are not in an "instance" of a class (and hence it does not have any member data/functions etc) - therefore when you access a non-static variable (which would only exist for an instance of the class) it says you can't, as you have no instance.

Comment: Your Man class is not static. This means it must have a reference to the outerclass.main is static and has no implicit outerclass.
The simple solution is make your Man class  static.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as the other answer doesn't address the `this`.

Comment: @IanBoyd I replaced the duplicate with one that does match the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### One approach

Declare `Man` class as static and you'll be able to access it from within `main()` which is static as well (not tied to any instance of class `Solution`):

`public static class Man`

### Another approach

We can also leave class `Man` non-static and create an instance-level factory-method which will create instances of `Man`:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create two object of every class here
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        Man m1 = solution.createMan("a1", "b1", 11);
        Man m2 = solution.createMan( "a2", "b2", 12);

        //output them to screen here
        System.out.println(m1.name + " " + m1.age + " " + m1.address);
        System.out.println(m2.name + " " + m2.age + " " + m2.address);    
    }

    Man createMan(String name, String address, int age) {
        return new Man(name, address, age);
    }

    //add your classes here
    public class Man {
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private int age;

        private Man(String name, String address, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        VerySimple alice = new VerySimple();
    }

    class VerySimple {
        private int age;
        private String name;
        //constructor

        VerySimple(int age, String name) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }

        //getter method
        int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        //setter method
        public void setAge(int a) {
            age = a;
        }

        //getter
        String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't waste your time answering old beginners questions that *should have been* closed as dups years ago.  Also, code-only answer are not much help.  You should start by explaining the point your code is designed to illustrate.   The explanation should be the real answer; the code is just the illustration.